# DNS to a free webhosting service

Tags: web-hosting, dns

I have a website which I host on a free hosting service (www.dhost.info) under a sub-domain of the hoster's website and I use a free URL forwarding service (www.dot.tk) to get a simple URL.

Besides URL forwarding, DotTK also offers a DNS service. I have little idea of what DNS is and how it works. DotTK requires me to add a Record, including Name, Type (A, CNAME etc.), TTL and Target.

How does this work, where do I get this information and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS stands for Domain Name Service. It ties the domain name to an IP address.

For example: You would tie example.com with an A record to the IP address 10.0.0.101 and you would tie the sub-domain www to example.com with a CNAME (alias) record.

If you have a domain name, you would assign the IP address given to you by your host or domain forwarding service to the domain name using a A record.

example.com A 10.0.0.101

And you would assign the alias www to example.com.

www CNAME example.com

The TTL times should have a default value. This is the Time To Live value in seconds. This is a time value that tells any DNS cache how long to cache the value for. If there is no default value, then 3600 should suffice.

It is likely that your domain forwarding service will have the information you need such as IP address. It may be that another setting be set other than the ones I outlined. These are example settings for the most common use. Most free hosts do not allow a domain name be assigned to a sub-domain. But this does not mean that this cannot be done. You will likely need to ask for assistance on this matter from the domain forwarding service or possibly the host.

Answer (score 1):

Many free website hosts do not support the usage of your own domain. If they do however support this feature then you will need to ask them to provide you with the DNS records or their name servers, with this information you then tell your domain the details provided, that is basically that... if your website is important you should move to a paid service for uptime and customer support.